# How to search a specific value in the whole dataframe and return its column and row indexes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, search

In pandas, I want to search for a specific value in the whole data frame and return its row and column index.

For example:

```
    apple pear orange banana
cat    1     2     3     4
dog    5     6     7     8    
fish   9     10    11    12
bird   13    14    15    16
```

Input: 10

Output: fish, pear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `np.where` for indices for match and indexing for match first value:

```
i, c = np.where(df == 10)

print ((df.index[i][0], df.columns[c][0]))
('fish', 'pear')
```

If possible value not exist in data use `next` with default value:

```
print ((next(iter(df.index[i]), 'no match'), next(iter(df.columns[c]), 'no match')))
('fish', 'pear')
```